# Commutativity of $\bigcup$, $\sum$, $\bigvee$

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

In my Caculus class we have derived the Real numbers by assuming that $\mathbb R$ is a field. That means that we have assumed that $+$ is commuative by postulating that $a + b = b + a$ for every $a,b\in\mathbb R$. We then showed that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$ is not commutative (e.g. consider $x_i = (-1)^i$). So we know that finite sums are commutative. That is, we postulated that $a+b=b+a$ for every $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and noticed that this only holds for FINITE sums.

When we introduced sets we made a similar assumptions for the union: we assumed that $A \cup B = B\cup A$ for sets $A,B$. However, $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ is in fact commutative. How do we actually know this?

In other words: In both cases (and one could additionally consider propositional calculus and $\vee$ which is commutative as well) we have assumed an equality which clearly holds only for a finite number (=2) elements. For the first case we could find a counter example to prove that it in fact only holds for a finite number of elements. For the second case there is none. But how do we know that? I mean from a logical perspective one should prove that starting with a finite number of elements it also holds for an arbitrary number of elements. Yet I have never seen a proof for that.
Can someone explain me this contradiction?

Comment: In what sense $∑x_i$ is not commutative ? It is not a "simple" sum...

Comment: The infinite set union is defined. The infinite disjunction is (usually) not: formulas of prop calculus are finite expressions.

Comment: The purported contradiction you have found shows that analogy in math is not enough: we have to rely on precise definitions.

Comment: You are not using the word "commutative" in the sense of its formal definition. A *binary* operation $\oplus$ is commutative if $a \oplus b = b \oplus a$ for all $a,b$ in the domain. However, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$ and $\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty$ are unary operations - they take a sequence of numbers or a sequence of sets, respectively. So some care is needed to state precisely the property you are looking at. What you are really saying is that their value is preserved (or not) under arbitrary permutations of the input sequence. Even $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty$ is closed under swapping any two elements.

Comment: @CarlMummert I have actually thought that $\bigoplus_{i\in I}Z_i$ is called commutative if $\bigoplus_{i\in }Z_i = \bigoplus_{i\in I}Z_{\phi(i)}$ for every permutation $\phi$.

$Z_1\oplus Z_2$ is then just a special case, namely $I = \{1,2\}$ (and using short hand notation).

Comment: So what you are saying is, if I understood you correctly, that commutativity is exclusively defined for binary operations. If a "big"-operators value for a given sequence is preserved under arbitrary permutations, then this property is similar to commutativity but different. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly - I wouldn't quite call it commutativity. Particularly because the value of a convergent $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty z_i$ is not changed if we flip any two of the terms, or more generally rearrange any finite number of them, and that has just as much right to be called "commutativity".

Answer (score 1):

We can't conclude from finite to infinite in general. In order to show that commutativity works for some specific operation, we need to prove that it holds for that specific operation using what we know about that specific operation.

Even the fact that the infinite operation *makes sense* isn't something we can show in general, and will have to rely on each specific case to see whether it does. Infinite sums usually do not make sense, although in some limited number of cases we can give it a consistent value. Union, by its nature, generalises from finite to infinite without issues.

Comment: "Union, by its nature, generalises from finite to infinite without issues." -- "by its nature", can you add some details to that? Because I don't see it. One could (naively) also claim that the sum by its nature generalises from finite to infinite (many people, even 1st year calculus students, think that)

Comment: The reason that union generalizes is that it is just defined by an existential quantifier: $\bigcup_i X_i = \{ z : (\exists i)[z \in X_i]\}$. By contrast the value of $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty x_i$ is the limit of the sequence of partial sums, and rearranging the terms arbitrarily makes a different sequence of partial sums that need not converge to the same value.

Comment: @SydAmerikaner Because a union is a set defined as "$x$ is contained in the union iff it is contained in at least one of the terms". There is nothing in that phrasing which really cares how many terms we have. Sums, on the other hand, really are defined only for two elements at a time, and by induction to any finite number of terms. However, for infinite sums we need entirely new machinery to even make sense of what it could mean.